# drools @KSession throws exception when using kmodule in separate jar

Tags: drools

using Drools 6.2.0.Final

i am using drools with a kmodules.xml and decisiontable inside a separate jar file. when i attempt to bind the @KSession to the spring application context it throws an nullpointer exception deep inside the annotation.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'oft.onlineservice.business.FeeRulesEngineTest': Injection of kie dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.kie.spring.annotations.AnnotationsPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AnnotationsPostProcessor.java:109)
```

using a simple junittest shows the problem.

```
public class FeeRulesEngineTest {

@KSession( "ksession1")
private StatelessKieSession ksession;

@KBase("feeDecisionTable")
private KieBase kbase;
```

the kmodule.xml

```
<kmodule xmlns="http://jboss.org/kie/6.0.0/kmodule">    
    <kbase name="feeDecisionTable" packages="oft.rulesengine" default="true">
        <ksession name="ksession1" type="stateless" default="true" >
        </ksession>    
    </kbase>    
</kmodule>
```

the spring config is using the annonation postprocessor.

```
<kie:import />
<bean id="kiePostProcessor"
      class="org.kie.spring.annotations.KModuleAnnotationPostProcessor"/>
```

my curent work around to is to use @Autowire for the KSession and KBase.

any idea what i am doing wrong?

thanks

-lp

Comment: Most likely: nothing if this is an org.kie class where the NPE is thrown. If you've made an mistake, it should be reported in an orderly manner. If you feel that this is a bug, report it as appropriate with Drools JIRA.

Comment: reported as DROOLS-845

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in Kie Services / Spring integration. The annotation assumes there's always a ReleaseId.

I created a Pull Request some weeks ago, so it should be solved in an upcoming version.

Ticket link: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/DROOLS-845